# Source not working within shell script

Tags: linux, bash, unix, anaconda

We operate on a Linux server and I need to run an R script within anaconda.

How do I engage the anaconda environment via a shell script.

Via the command line:

```
$  source anaconda 
$  Rscript <file.R>
```

works just fine.

If anaconda is already engaged the following .sh works fine:

```
#!/bin/bash
PATH=$PATH:/usr/local/bin/anaconda
echo Rscript ./name.R
```

Is there a version of:

```
#!/bin/bash
PATH=$PATH:/usr/local/bin
echo source anaconda; Rscript ./name.R
```

That would open anconda and run the script?

My anaconda is located within ./anaconda.
I've tried setting that as my initial path.

Thanks!

Comment: just remove `echo`: line 2 = `source ./anaconda` line 3 = Rscript ./name.R` -- I assume the "anaconda" file is in the same directory as the name.R file.

Comment: Didn't work. Anaconda is a package that contain Rscript. It needs to be activated in order for Rscript to work. I'm getting the error:

./test.sh: line 4: Rscript: command not found

Comment: What is `type Rscript` after you ran `source anaconda` at the prompt? What does it emit from your script? To be clear, `source` **should** work fine when it's run from a script (if the interpreter really is bash; if you ran `sh yourscript`, the `#!/bin/bash` shebang is ignored, and all bets are off).

Comment: All that said, the `echo`s are obvious problems. Why are they there in your code sample (`echo source anaconda`, not `source anaconda`)?

Comment: Not sure. I've removed them per above.

Type after sourcing anaconda yields:

blah/anaconda/anaconda-5.0/bin/Rscript

Comment: ...btw, if you want to log what's done during the `source` command, you can easily enough trace your script's execution. Add the line `PS4='+($?) $BASH_SOURCE:$FUNCNAME:$LINENO:'; set -x` after the shebang and before the `source` command, and amend the result into the question.

Comment: ...well, that `type` output looks exactly like it should -- if `type Rscript` gives that output (from your script), then `Rscript` certainly shouldn't be "command not found". Anyhow, the log requested above would still be useful.

Comment: Works great. Syntax error...

Thanks for everything

Answer (score 0):

What we're missing is the contents of the `anaconda` file. I'm thinking it creates the `Rscript` command as an **alias**, since the shell by default does not expand aliases unless the shell is interactive. For example:

Interactive, all is well

```
$ cat > anaconda
alias Rscript='echo this is Rscript:'
$ source ./anaconda
$ Rscript foo bar
this is Rscript: foo bar
```

But in a script, I can reproduce your error

```
$ cat > test.sh
#!/bin/bash
source ./anaconda
Rscript foo bar
$ bash test.sh
test.sh: line 3: Rscript: command not found
```

Forcing bash to be interactive:

```
$ bash -i test.sh
this is Rscript: foo bar
```

Try this:

```
#!/bin/bash
shopt -s expand_aliases
source /path/to/anaconda
Rscript ./name.R
```

Comment: `anaconda` is a script bundled with a publicly-available piece of software. Have you inspected that software to determine whether it does in fact set an alias?